# Problem getting a process' writing/reading bytes and cpu usage in Python 3.8

Tags: process, python-3.8

recently in my school finals project i needed to write a function that return a process' writing and reading bytes as well as it's cpu usage. I have tried using Psutil, tried using WMI (couldn't find a way to recieve the writing and reading bytes through that) and even tried combining them. At the end though i get an access denied error every time on almost all processes by the Psutil. Would love some help in solving this problem.

Edit: using Windows 10

this is the code i currently have:

```
import wmi
import psutil
from elevate import elevate

elevate()


c = wmi.WMI()
process_watcher = c.Win32_Process.watch_for("creation")
while True:
  new_process = process_watcher()
  pid = new_process.Processid
  name = new_process.Caption
  try:
    curr_process = psutil.Process(pid=pid)
    try:
      # get the number of CPU cores that can execute this process
      cores = len(curr_process.cpu_affinity())
    except psutil.AccessDenied:
      cores = 0
      # get the CPU usage percentage
    cpu_usage = curr_process.cpu_percent()
    try:
      # get the memory usage in bytes
      memory_usage = curr_process.memory_full_info().uss
    except psutil.AccessDenied:
      memory_usage = 0
    # total process read and written bytes
    io_counters = curr_process.io_counters()
    read_bytes = io_counters.read_bytes
    write_bytes = io_counters.write_bytes

    print(pid + ": " + name + ", Write bytes: " + write_bytes + ", cpu usage: "+ cpu_usage)
  except:
    print("Access Denied")
```

Comment: I f you are getting an acces denied error you need to run the program as an administrator

Comment: I already have (you can see the "from elevate import elevate" and then "elevate()" which runs the program as admin)

Comment: What OS are you using linux , windows, or macOs

Comment: Im using Windows